# Passing a list of senders to the sender parameter of @receiver decorator

Tags: python, django, web, event-handling

So at the moment, I'm working on my Django project and I have a signal receiver function that looks like this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Task, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre_1')
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TaskHistory, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre_2')
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TaskUser, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre_3')
def task_handler_pre(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # do some stuff
```

In an attempt to make the code look cleaner, I was wondering whether would it be possible to do something like this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=[Task, TaskHistory, TaskUser], dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre')
def task_handler_pre(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # do some stuff
```

i.e. Does the `sender` parameter accepts a list of senders as a valid argument ? If not, then does the value of the `dispatch_uid` parameter within the `@receiver` decorator, have to be different for each individual sender, or can it be the same i.e.

As mentioned previously, my receiver function looks like this at the moment:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Task, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre_1')
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TaskHistory, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre_2')
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TaskUser, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre_3')
def task_handler_pre(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # do some stuff
```

What difference would it make if I make the following change:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Task, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre')
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TaskHistory, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre')
@receiver(pre_save, sender=TaskUser, dispatch_uid='core.models.task_handler_pre')
def task_handler_pre(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # do some stuff
```

i.e. make the value of the `dispatch_uid` parameter the same ( `core.models.task_handler_pre` ) for each individual sender. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the code which use sender in `https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/signals.py`

```py
        partial_method = partial(method, receiver, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(sender, str):
            apps = apps or Options.default_apps
            apps.lazy_model_operation(partial_method, make_model_tuple(sender))
        else:
            return partial_method(sender)
```

Probably, you can do something by using a Callable (not sure).

But in your case, why you do not make you own receiver decorator which loop on senders for creating all signal connecting ?

Or calling connect function in the ready method of your apps ? Probably more cleaner than using decorators